# try except with chunksize iterator

Tags: python, pandas, chunks, try-except

I would like to read a big csv file so I use the `chunksize` method iterator of pandas . But I obtain a `ParserError` so I thought using the try except and when I get this error I would like to pass to the next chunk iteration . 
So I tested that :

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",iterator=True)
d=True
while d==True : 
    try:
        df.get_chunk(500000)
    exept ParserError : 
         pass
    except StopIteration:
         d=False
```

But I obtain this error :

`NameError : name "ParserError" is not defined` .

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: You probably meant `pd.errors.ParserError`

Comment: You worte `exept` instead of `except`.

Answer (score 5):

Recent versions of pandas allow `read_csv` to accept a `chunksize` argument you can pass while iterating.

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv("file.csv", 
                         chunksize=500000, 
                         iterator=True, 
                         error_bad_lines=False,
                         engine='python'):
    ...  # do something with `chunk`
```

There's no need for a `while` loop, or for error handling, because `pd.read_csv` automatically raises a `StopIteration` when it is exhausted which the `for` handles and exits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I try your method , i get an error : Error tokenizing data . C error : Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file

Comment: @day Added another attribute - `engine='python'`, try it again.

Comment: it might not be in the OP's interest to use a for loop, in which case your answer isn't helpful